# Jersey (2.8) package scan for resources across multiple Maven modules

Tags: maven, jersey, maven-jetty-plugin, multi-module

I have a (Maven) multi module project that has Jersey set up in a web-app module and integration tests in an integration-tests module. Jersey is configured via a `ResourceConfig` class as

```
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
  public Application() {
      register(RequestContextFilter.class);
      packages("foo.bar.baz", "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base");
      register(ValidationFeature.class);
  }
}
```

and set up for deployment in `web.xml` as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5">
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:conf/spring/*.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>foo.bar.baz.application.Application</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo_bar_service/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Both of these files reside in the web-app module. Building the project and deploying it on Tomcat works flawlessly.

For integration tests I am having Maven start Jetty via Maven Jetty plugin in the pre-integration-test phase, pointing the source directory for the web-app in the web-app module. Relevant parts of pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <!-- The Basics -->
  <artifactId>integration-test</artifactId>
  <parent>
    <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <path>${project.parent.basedir}</path>
    <checkstyle.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}/build/rules</checkstyle.basedir>
    <pmd.config.location>${project.parent.basedir}/build/rules/pmd_rules.xml</pmd.config.location>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
      <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <!-- Build Settings -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Maven Checkstyle Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Maven JAR Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Maven Resources Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Jetty plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.26</version>
        <configuration>
          <daemon>false</daemon>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
          <stopKey>jettystop</stopKey>
          <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
          <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
          <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/mobile-api-svc-webapp/src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
          <webXml>${project.parent.basedir}/mobile-api-svc-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
          <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Maven Failsafe Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

NB! To test the jetty server I set `daemon` to false so that I can ping the servlet from a browser.

After starting the Jetty server with `mvn verify` I noticed that Jersey does not pick up the resource classes (they also reside in the web-app module), hence correct url-s give a 404 Not Found.

My suspicion that the problem is with package scanning seems to be confirmed. After modifying `ResourceConfig` by adding `registerClasses(RESOURCE_CLASSES);` url-s handled by Jersey work correctly.

My Questions are (to which I have found no answers): 
- is there way package scanning can be fixed to work across modules?
- is there a way to configure the same Jersey servlet with two `ResoureConfig` files, so that I can put the ugly hack of registering classes in the integration-test module?